# How can I fix this leak in my kitchen sink?

Tags: leak, kitchen-sink

The large grey nut keeps camming at the top of the threads, and as a result that black rubber gasket above it doesn't compress enough to form a seal.  So, I'm unable to fill that side of my sink with water, unless I want water dripping into my cabinet.

What is the correct fix this this problem?

[image]

Comment: So the threads are damaged, or is the drain basket the wrong one for a sink this thin, so the threads just run out before the thing clamps properly?

Comment: The bottom of the sink looks a little damaged?  You could make sure there's plumber's putty on the top side, maybe that'd add a little?

Comment: @Ecnerwal It is possible the drain basket was not intended for this thin sink.   It's been too long for me to remember, but I replaced the sink with a new one (similar thickness, but possibly not identical) and I might have reused the "drain basket" that I had on hand.

Comment: @rogerdpack What are you seeing that looks like damage? (1) There's that black rubber sheet dangling at one corner -- I have no idea why that is on the underside, it seems to do nothing.  I think the adhesive is just failing.  (2) there's that white stuff showing around the gasket/sink interface;  I think that's just dried grody stuff from the last time someone forgot and filled this sink with dirty dish water.    (I'll be sure to double-check on that.)

Comment: Right above the gasket.  May want to take the whole gasket off and snap a picture without the gasket at all, to check condition of the metal.  Stuff should not be able to seep through, though it almost makes sense if you can't seal the gasket (might be old plumber's putty? I was referring to adding new...) :)

Comment: The black rubber sheet is a more half-hearted than usual attempt to deaden the sound of a thin stainless sink. More typically there's a full coating sprayed on. There's either corrosion from leakage or stray putty at the gasket/sink interface.

Answer (score 5):

"Buy a new one that fits this sink correctly, or isn't damaged" seems like the fix, though I suppose the "stack 3 gaskets and hope" approach would be popular with some folks.

If you could find one much thicker gasket it would be less of a kludge, or if you could find a longer nut that fits this basket that could work too.

Comment: I don't have a sense that there is damage.  It feels more like the ring runs out of threads (and thus, begins "camming" before it has a chance to squeeze the rubber.)

Multiple/thicker gaskets would be my default choice, had I not thought to ask here first.

Are there really taller/thicker nuts to be had?  I'm clueless here, I assumed it was a standard issue nut.

Comment: Normally that nut would be fully tightened before the drain pipes were connected. Certainly worth a look for a thicker gasket.

Comment: All fixed now, with a brand new basket+nut+gasket.  I suspect that at some point in the past, someone mixed up brand A nut with brand B basket.

Answer (score 1):

Water come from the top side of the sink. That is where the seal has failed.
Unless the basket assembly or the sink is bent, this process has been a success for every leak of this type that I have encountered.

Remove the entire drain basket. Clean all the parts thoroughly. Apply a generous amount of plumbers putty to the underside of the flange of the basket and push it firmly into the hole.  Apply a [Teflon thread sealer](https://www.oatey.com/products/oatey-great-white-pipe-joint-compound-with-ptfe--275767012) to the threads of the basket. Install 1 rubber gasket and tighten by hand. Give the putty 1 minute to compress and tighten again using a large pair of slip joint pliers.  ( Do not over tighten)  the thread sealer will make it feel like the nut is not tight.  Trust it.  Clean the excess putty of the inside of the basket. Run water to test.

Comment: This sounds like decent advice.  What about my observation that the nut runs out of threads (on the basket) before it compresses the gasket?

Comment: All fixed now, with a brand new basket+nut+gasket.  I think your advice was generally good, though.